# Problems with datagridview / autoresizecolumns and rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a huge problems every time I try to resize my columns and rows. I'm trying to autoresize the columns and the rows with the function:

```
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
dataGridView1.AutoResizeRows();
```

If i put this two lines after I pass the `datasource` to `dataview`, it doesn't work. I tried to handle the `DataSourceBindingComplete`, and idem it doesn't work. I tried to set it in the `form.designer.cs` and it doesn't work. then
I tried to make a button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
     dataGridView1.AutoResizeRows();
}
```

and when I click the button everything works perfectly!!! It resizes all my columns and my rows. But i don't want this. I want it automatic.
Can you guys help me please and explain why it does that? Doesn't make sense, inside the original code it doesn't work, but in a separate button it works.

Comment: Set the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` and `AutoSizeRowsMode` properties in the designer.  They are both `None` by default. For the record, you should never be asking a question where the answer is setting a property in the designer because you should have already taken a thorough look at every property displayed there and what they do.

Comment: They are already none! Both of them. And I tried to put all the peoprieties, fill, allcell, displayed cell, nothing changed

Comment: That's the point! They are `None` by default but if you expect the columns and rows to resize automatically then it should be obvious that you need them to NOT be `None`. If you expect them to resize automatically then you have to specify HOW they should do that.  If you don't tell them how by setting those properties, they won't do it.

Comment: I just tested a `DataGridView` with its `AutoSizeColumnsMode` property set to `AllCells` and as soon as I added a long text value the column got wider automatically, exactly as you'd expect. Either you're doing something wrong or something is broken on your system. That's how it's supposed to work and that's how it did work for me. I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: But I already tried with all the proprieties on the design! The problem is when I'm going to autoresize them after the datagrid is complete it doesn't work, if I do trough a button it works!! doesn't make sense

Comment: Like I said, it works as it should for me so I don't know what to tell you.  If you can provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue and then we can test the same thing you did. If that works for us then we can conclude that something is broken on your system and if it doesn't work then we might have a chance of diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Ok guys, I'm so sorry I put in both of the proprieties ALLCELL and it work, what was wrong was a foreach cicle to set FILL to all the columns. Now everything works, but the datagrid doesn't fit all the form. How I can resize all the columns and make them to fill the form as well??

Comment: That's a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize that it took me more than a year to see this post...

Here's what I did to make this "automatic".

```
private void AutoResizeGrid()
    {
        if (dataGridView.Columns.Count < 1) return;
        dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells);
        dataGridView.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells);
    }


    private void MatrixDataGridView_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Visible) return;
        AutoResizeGrid();
    }

    private void MatrixDataGridView_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Visible) return;
        AutoResizeGrid();
    }
```

Before adding this code, I went to the Designer and I set "AutoSizeColumnsMode" and "AutoSizeRowsMode" both to "DisplayedCells". This causes automation when the grid first receives the data. The code above causes automation when a resize or scroll event happens.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me.

Set AutoSizeColumnsMode and AutoSizeRowsMode values to AllCells from None in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode` before you set the source, if possible?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = SourceList; // Your Collection here
    dataGridView1.AutoResizeRows();
}
```